# How to display N/A when Name column is blank for custid1 in ID column and for custid2 we have 2 entries as 1.Prem, 2. (2 is blank)

Tags: vertica

I have a table like below,I'm using vertica data base sql

```
| Name     | Cust ID  |
|          | 1        |
|          | 2        |
|Prem      | 2        |
```

For cust ID 1 the name is blank, so it should display and N/A, for cust ID 2 we have 2 entries, which are 1 is blank and 2 is Prem, so blank should be ignored and should display Prem.

The final out put should be like this,

```
|Name   | Cust ID |
|N/A    |1        |
|Prem   |2        |
```

The final output should be like this,

```
|Name   | Cust ID |
|N/A    |1        |
|Prem   |2        |
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if the non-empty name of the same cust-id is always the same in multiple rows. Note that I use the NULL value for non-existent data. An empty string and NULL are two different things, for me.

```
WITH
indata("name",custid) AS (
            SELECT NULL  , 1
  UNION ALL SELECT NULL  , 2
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Prem', 2
)
SELECT
  IFNULL(MAX("name"),'N/A') AS "name"
, custid
FROM indata
GROUP BY custid;
-- out Null display is "(null)".
-- out  name | custid 
-- out ------+--------
-- out  N/A  |      1
-- out  Prem |      2
```